# Show variable name in plot as greek symbol?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I want to plot a correlation matrix in `R` by using the function `ggcorr` of the package `GGally`. As an example consider the data frame

```
names <- c("a","b")
ex <- data.frame(a=c(0.5,0.5),b=c(0.5,0.5),row.names=names)
```

and the matrix

```
ggcorr(ex).
```

Is it possible replace a variable name by a greek symbol as tau (wlog replace "a" by tau)?
I tried

```
names <- c(tau,"b")
ex <- data.frame(tau=c(0.5,0.5),b=c(0.5,0.5),row.names=names)
```

,
but this simply plots the name 'tau' and not the greek symbol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the greek locale in your system, you can simply do:

`ex <- data.frame(τ=c(0.5,0.5),b=c(0.5,0.5),row.names=names)`

```
> ex
    τ   b
a 0.5 0.5
b 0.5 0.5
```

Or   you can run:

```
Sys.setlocale('LC_CTYPE', 'greek')
```

Answer (score 1):

A more general solution is to use `ggcorr(ex, parse = T)`.

```
ggcorr(data.frame(partialdiff = sort(rnorm(10)),
                  beta = sort(rnorm(10)),
                  Delta = rnorm(10),
                  aleph = rnorm(10),
                  Upsilon1 = rnorm(10),
                  phi = sort(rnorm(10)),
                  phi1 = rnorm(10)), parse = T, label = T)
```

[image]